# Can web2py serve REST data of many-to-may tables via parse_as_rest?

Tags: rest, many-to-many, web2py

I need to serve REST data about a many-to-many relationship.  I've been playing with web2py's lovely parse_as_rest functionality, but can't quite get the many-to-many thing working.

As an example, let's take standard users and groups.

Tables:

1. user

   - id
   - user_name
2. group

   - id
   - group_name
3. membership

   - id
   - user_id
   - group_id

What pattern do I need to use to serve a url that will give me all group_name's that a user belongs to?

```
patterns = [
"/user[user]",
"/user[user]/id/{user.id}",
"/user[user]/id/{user.id}/membership[membership.user_id]",

# This is the line that I can't make yet:
#"/user[user]/id/{user.id}/membership[membership.user_id]/group<WHAT GOES HERE>",

"/group[group]",
"/group[group]/id/{group.id}",
]
parser = db.parse_as_rest(patterns, args, vars)
```

With the non-commented lines above, I can get to these urls:

1. .../user
2. .../user/id/1
3. .../user/id/1/membership
4. .../group
5. .../group/id/3

URL #3 shows me all my memberships, and I can then make several separate calls to URL #5 to get the group_name values, but there's got to be a way to do this with one call.

Help me StackOverflow!  You're my only hope.

EDIT: Fixed bad cutting and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

This question is in top of Google search for that topic.

Just start building query from the many-to-many table.

```
/user[membership]/id/{membership.user_id}/groups[group.id]
```

You don't really need 'user' table for this request.

Then request to "/user/id/22/groups" will give you all groups not only their IDs.